# How to create a new field collection+fields in a programmatically added content type

Tags: entities

I'm very new to creating modules and I'm creating a content type for the first time programmatically.

Creating the content type works fine, I've even added some fields. But now I'd like to create a new field in that content type which is a field collection.

I can't find a good spot on the internet that explains how I can add a new field collection to a new content type. All programmatically in one run.

Can anyone help me out how to achieve this?

It involves this [contributed module](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection).

Comment: The field you are wanting to add. Is it from this contrib module? https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection

Comment: Yes, yes it is. Sorry; should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I googled _create field_collection programmatically_ and [this example](https://www.drupal.org/node/1106182#comment-4653514) was from my first search result.

> Thought I would post my solution for programmatically creating a field collection, along with an attached field, during a module install. The example is specific to my use, but easily modified to add the field types you need. Of course, if there is an easier way please feel free to add your thoughts. This works with the current 7.x-1.x-dev branch.
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Create a Field Collection field and attach collection node reference
>  */
> function _create_field_collection() {
>   $t = get_t();
>
>   $fields_array = array(
>     array(
>       'field' => array(
>         'field_name' => 'bir_collection',
>         'label' => $t('BIR Collection Nodes'),
>         'cardinality' => -1,
>         'type' => 'field_collection',
>       ),
>       'instance' => array(
>         'field_name' => 'bir_collection',
>         'entity_type' => 'node',
>         'bundle' => 'article',
>         'label' => $t('BIR Collection Nodes'),
>         'description' => '',
>         'widget' => array('type' => 'field_collection_embed'),
>         'required' => 1,
>       ),
>     ),
>     array(
>       'field' => array(
>         'field_name' => 'bir_collection_node',
>         'type' => 'node_reference',
>         'label' => '',
>         'cardinality' => 1,
>         'settings' => array(
>           'referenceable_types' => array(
>             'bir_specimen' => 'bir_specimen',
>             'bir_image' => 'bir_image',
>             'bir_locality' => 'bir_locality',
>             'bir_view' => 'bir_view',
>           ),
>         ),
>       ),
>       'instance' => array(
>         'field_name' => 'bir_collection_node',
>         'entity_type' => 'field_collection_item',
>         'bundle' => 'bir_collection',
>         'label' => '',
>         'cardinality' => 1,
>         'description' => '',
>         'widget' => array('type' => 'node_reference_autocomplete'),
>         'display' => array('default' => array('type' => 'node_reference_default')),
>       )
>     ),
>   );
>
>   // Loop through fields array and create field and instance
>   foreach ($fields_array as $field) {
>     // Check if field already exists
>     if (!field_info_field($field['field']['field_name'])) {
>       field_create_field($field['field']);
>     }
>
>     // Check if instance exists
>     if (!field_info_instance($field['instance']['entity_type'], $field['instance']['field_name'], $field['instance']['bundle'])) {
>       field_create_instance($field['instance']);
>     }
>   }  
> }
> ```

First field in the `$fields_array` array is the `field_collection` type field that you add to your `node` entity. (field_name: bir_collection)

The second field in the array is the field which is added to your `field_collection_item` entity (Notice the bundle in the instance is same as your field_name on node: bir_collection. This is how the connection is made). In this particular example, it's a `node_reference` type field, but this can be any other field type that's available to your Drupal instance.

The order has to be in this sequence, since you need to add the `field_collection` type field to your node to create the `field_collection_item` entity, then you add the fields to your `field_collection_item` entity.

Comment: Thanks, I honestly didn't find it with the exact same search params! It may work in the current setup I have but it says it can't create a field with type "node_reference". Now I can't remember needing an extra module for field collections via Drupal itself; so why now? And what module would that be that can handle type => 'node_reference' ?

Comment: @CaptainCarl the `node_reference` type field is provided by [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module. However, that piece of code is just an example though, you can have any different field attached to your `field_collection` entity. Such as `text` or `longtext` or `date` etc. It doesn't have to be `node_reference`.

Comment: @CaptainCarl check the edit, hope it's clearer.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a million for the explanation! I needed that most of all I think ;)